# 2 Primary keys in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql

**I have been given an ERD of a database that I need to create in PostgreSQL. Shown below.**

[Daterbase ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMu7O.png)

As you can see on the table Enroll, there are **two primary keys** that are also foreign keys as well that need to be in that table, how would I go about creating this table this is what I have so far,

```
create table enroll( 
 class_code varchar(15) primary key references class(class_code), 
 trn_num int primary key references TRAINEE(trn_num), 
 enroll_date date, 
 enroll_grade int
);
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This sounds like homework, but here's a hint - there's not two primary keys, there's one primary key consisting of two columns.

Comment: University work, brilliant, I think I know what you are talking about! Cheers for the help! @EricPetroelje

Comment: [Unique Constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html) does not work?

Answer (score 5):

Answer: Create a composite primary key.

```
create table enroll( 
   class_code varchar(15) references class(class_code), 
   trn_num int  references TRAINEE(trn_num),
   enroll_date date, 
   enroll_grade int,
   primary key(class_code, trn_num)

);
```